# How to make the ASP File Upload control accept large files?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I would like to upload files using the ASP `FileUpload` control. However, if I try and increase the limit to about 10000 kB, it doesn't work and accepts files only upto 4 MB in size and I get an error saying that the connection to the server was reset. I referred: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/ASPNET20FileUpload.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478971.aspx, but when I modified the web.config.comments file, nothing happened. Where am I going wrong?

Also, I wanted to know how this would work when I deploy it on the web server. I'm asking because in the code behind, I'm still giving a hard coded value for the path where the file is to be uploaded. How does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="360"/>
</system.web>
```

This is what you are looking for. Change the `executionTimeout` property in web.config file.

According to [this website](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Limiting-the-File-Upload-Size-in-ASPNET.aspx),

> **maxRequestLength** - Attribute limits
>   the file upload size for ASP.NET
>   application. This limit can be used to
>   prevent denial of service attacks
>   (DOS) caused by users posting large
>   files to the server. The size
>   specified is in kilobytes. As
>   mentioned earlier, the default is
>   "4096" (4 MB). Max value is "1048576"
>   (1 GB) for .NET Framework 1.0/1.1 and
>   "2097151" (2 GB) for .NET Framework
>   2.0.
>
> **executionTimeout** - Attribute indicates
>   the maximum number of seconds that a
>   request is allowed to execute before
>   being automatically shut down by the
>   application. The executionTimeout
>   value should always be longer than the
>   amount of time that the upload process
>   can take.

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: Perfecto! Thank you! :) Can you please also explain the second part of the question? :)

Comment: @Akshay: The 2nd part of the question is a bit hard to understand. Are you asking why this works when deployed but not in the dev environment? Or is it about the path that you are saving the file to? Can you show some code?

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: The code is same as given in any of those links that I referred to in the question. This part: `FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\Uploads\" & FileUpload1.FileName)` is what I am interested in. When its hosted on the server, how can this still work? Are there any modifications needed to be made?

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray:And I mean, when its online, the web hosting company would have their own database right? So, how would this work then?

Comment: Do you want the file to be saved in a database or in the server? If you want to save files in the server side, I suggest you use virtual directories.

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: Ok. This is what I asked this question for. I need to make a website, where the client can login, upload a file and view its contents later. So, we'll be hosting this site on the server and the files would be stored online as well. The file would invariably be an xls spreadsheet and I need to export that to the database, where he can view it from later. What are the changes that need to be made in order for this work?

Comment: Well if you need to store the file in a database (which I strongly advise against), the code obviously needs to be changed. You will have a column of type `Binary` (if your XLS is less than 8000 bytes) or `IMAGE` (Don't confuse with this type with an actual image). And then you will use a parameterized SQL query to insert your file to the database. http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/08/31/storing-and-retrieving-docpdfxls-files-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: No no. Not in the database, but on the web server. Is that advisable? But then again, how else would it work if its not on the server?

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: The file needs to be imported to a database table, but will be saved/uploaded online to the web domain hoster's server, which will then be viewed as a GridView. I will be using the `openrowset` command for this. My question is: the `openrowset` needs a source to be specified. How can I do this if the file is on the server? And, if you know anything about `openrowset`, would it work on the server?

Comment: There are few ways you can handle this situation. The best way in my opinion is that you save the file in server and save the path of it in the database. And you can have a page that will get lets say get the PK of the file as a query string, queries the database for the actual path the file was saved, and serves it to the user. That way you will not need to show the end user, the actual path of the file. And sorry I haven't used `openrowset` command. And yes the file will be in the server, but not IN the database :)

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: That is what I had in mind. However, is there a way I can test this on my machine before actual deployment? `openrowset` is basically when you specify what the source of the Excel file is, and it copies cell-by-cell into the designed table. The table can then be viewed in a `GridView`. And this is why I'm so concerned about the source/location of the file.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the source to an excel file which resides in a virtual directory? I suggest you open another question with your new  concern :)

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: I haven't because I don't know how I can do that while actually not using a web hosting service. And, look out for a new question. ;)