# HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request due to FileUpload control in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http

I have a web form(.net framework 4) which contains a submit button and a FileUpload control.When I debug the website from visual studio 2010, the form appears as intended.When I upload a file with size > 438k(as per my observations.Actual value of maximum file size is unknown,but for file with size 200K, it is working),I get the following error on clicking the button.

```
Server Error in '/Dpp2012New' Application.
HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.
Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0
```

When I upload a file with size less than above limit, code functions as usual.
The onclick event handler codebehind is:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        MsgBox("Has file!")
    End If
End Sub
```

After scratching through the net([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936571/how-to-make-the-asp-file-upload-control-accept-large-files) SO post), I added this in web.config:

```
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="360"/>
    </system.web>
```

This should have solved the issue.But it does not.
Any help to solve the problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have custom error pages enabled, or first-chance exceptions for debugging?

Comment: What did u mean by custom error pages? or first-chance exceptions? and how to check whether they are enabled or not?@STW

Comment: what code is present inside Submit button ?

Comment: @WaqarJanjua http://pastebin.com/4sDHqQfX

Comment: @rahulserver please post your code here, and not on an external source.

Comment: @rahulserver link is not working, and STW asked about custom errors, Custom errors are defined in webconfig file.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua I do not have anything like custom error pages enabled in webconfig file.The link is working for me.However, The code is now pasted in the question.

Comment: @KP the code is now pasted.see edit.

Comment: in your button code you read an excel file and insert the excel data in to the database. Do you place a breakpoint in your button code and check that at which line the exactly error occurs ?

Comment: and where you have define the connectionString variable ? I'm unable to see that. I think you are not connected to the database. Please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please debug your site and check whether you are connected to the database ? I think you are not connected.
If you are facing a problem in uploading large files then you must add the following attribute to your webconfig file.

```
<system.web> 
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="20000" /> 
</system.web>
```

maxRequestLength is the maximum file size.

**Updated Answer:**
Run your site on a different browser like google chrome, Internet explorer.

Comment: Yes,I am connected to the database.The connectionString variable is defined as a global variable in the beginning of vb file.I have tried to debug the site, but it does not reach the breakpoint, even at the starting line of the onclick event handler! before it gives the 400 error!

Comment: try one thing, add a new page to the site, copy the whole code from this page to the new page, and check whether the code works on new page or not.

Comment: Still does not work.I then created a new page with a simple button and a textbox.In button's onclick handler, i placed a message box which shows what was entered in textbox using javascript alert.It works.This shows that there is problem in the onclick event handler of the form in question.

Comment: if you are unable to debug the site, then the problem may be is in your site. Your code looks fine.

Comment: It was a browser issue. The problem does not come in chrome or ie.But in mozilla it does.For me now the problem is solved.Thanks all who helped!