# fileupload control causing server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, file-upload

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String fn = FileUpload1.FileName;
    string fp = Server.MapPath("images");
    if (fp.EndsWith("\\") == false)
    {
        fp = fp + "\\";
    }
    fp = fp + fn;
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(fp);
}
}
```

on runnning this code, i receive the following error:

> Server Error in '/WebSite11' Application
>   HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.
>   Version Information:
>    ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

Comment: run your site on a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

If the images folder is located at the root of your site then path should be this

```
string fp = Server.MapPath(~"/images");
```

and also try to run the site on a different brwose bcz few days ago i saw the same issue but when he rans the code on a different browse it works fine.

see the following post
[HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request due to FileUpload control in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400637/http-error-400-bad-request-due-to-fileupload-control-in-vb-net/11407612#11407612)